80s/90s kids movie, possibly Halloween themed, boy removed from grandfather's care and put with stict family who don't allow chocolate
I'm looking for a movie that may have been a TV movie/special, probably late 80s/early 90s. Colour, live-action, English language, North American. I'm not sure why I think it's Halloween themed; perhaps I watched it at Halloween? I have a hazy memory of the kids dressed up at one point, but I'm not sure of that.
A youngish boy is living with his grandfather. They're fond of eating candy, maybe especially chocolate? The boy is assigned to do a school project with another classmate, a girl that maybe he doesn't like? I recall that when she goes over to work on the project she drink a whole glass of chocolate milk in one go and maybe asks for more? For some reason the boy is removed from his grandfather's care, although the grandfather isn't dead because later he talks to his grandson through the school fence and sneaks him chocolate. The boy is placed with a strict family and it turns out the female classmate is also living there. I think the foster parents call them Kid 1 and 2 or something like that? They're not allowed to have chocolate.
I think this stuff was earlier in the movie but I don't remember what the rest of the movie was about. 

It might be "George's Island" from 1989?

@steelerfan Yes, that's it, thank you so much! I've been wondering what movie it was for ages!

The movie you are describing sounds like George's Island from 1989.
George, a ten year old boy lives with his Grandfather.  George is placed in foster care after his Grandfather is deemed unfit to care for him.
The foster family keeps George locked in the basement. George and the other foster child, Bonnie escape on Halloween night.
From Wikipedia:

Ten-year-old George lives in a dilapidated home near the Halifax Harbour with his grandfather, Captain Waters. Captain Waters is a wheelchair-bound former sailor. 
He is fond of telling George ghost stories. He volunteers an old story about
  the time he saw Captain Kidd's ghost out in Halifax Harbour. 
When George learns in school about Kidd's supposed buried treasure out on
  nearby George's Island, he volunteers the story, and is punished by
  nosy school teacher Miss Birdwood. 
Miss Birdwood believes that the root of George's outburst is "trouble at home." She
  launches her own sneaky investigation to find out the truth. When she
  discovers that Captain Waters has a fondness for grog, she reports the
  family to Mr. Droonfield at Child Services. 
While Mr. Droonfield determines a course of action, George is temporarily placed
  with a foster family, the Beanes who keep him locked up in a basement cell. On Halloween night,
  George and the Beanes' other adoptee, Bonnie, escape
  with Captain Waters and head for safety on George's Island. Miss
  Birdwood and Mr. Droonfield give chase, but they accidentally awaken
  the ghosts of Captain Kidd and his men, who think that
  the intruders are after their chest of gold.

